# trusted Idp not found using onelogin

Tags: asp.net, onelogin

Hi I've setup a onelogin developer account, downloaded asp.net c# source code.

I've tried to follow the example shown, it currently tell me SOMETHING WENT WRONG... Trusted IdP not found, but i'm shore I've set one up.

If someone can point me the right direction, would be most grateful.

Comment: Please add some code snippet in order we can help you. Thank you

Comment: In AccountSettings.cs, I update the certificate with the one generated with developer account
updated the 
 string idp_sso_target_url = "https://{account}.onelogin.com/saml/proxy/{number}", with the generated proxy link

I think it the configuration setting in the developer account, the code is straightforward

Comment: Also updated the issuer in AppSettings.cs to match the one in developer account